# Sharepoint syncronize

Tags: sync

I've synced a lot of sharepoint document/lists into my Explore.

The problem is, I way to often get a message when opening a document that says "A newer version is available" - even though it's been some time since anyone had it open.

Is there anyway to make sure that Sharepoint(or is it actually onedrive?) sync more often then the case is now?

Comment: Could you clarify this question a bit? If possible add a screenshot?

Comment: When standing in Sharepoint(via browser) Theres a sync option, that lets you sync sharepoint to explore. Having done that, I now have access through windows explore. But, half of the times I open shared documents im greeted with a message saying "Someone updated this document, open a newer version from server" Even though it hasnt been open in a while. So the library sync to explore doesnt happend "often enough"